# Need different price formatting on list view and product view

Tags: magento-1.7

I need different price formatting on list view and product view but both views use the same template `template\catalog\product\price.phtml` to display the price. Is there a way to distinguish if list view or product view is calling the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use the following two to distinguish

Calling the following

```
<?php if (Mage::registry('current_category')) { ?>
     then show this price
<?php }else if(Mage::registry('current_product')) {?>
    show this price
<?php } ?>
```

will either return null if the objects haven't been set (i.e. you're on a page without a category or a product), or return category and product objects.

If a product object is returned you're on a product page.

Answer (score 1):

To distinguish the price on list view and product view, you can use the following :

```
<?php if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'product')
{ 
    // price formatting for product view page
}
else
{
   //  price formatting for product list page
}
?>
```